# Get text from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've made an ExpandableListView with ArrayList as following:`

```
public void setChildGroupData() {

    /**
     * Add Data For TecthNology
     */
    ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Java");
    child.add("Drupal");
    child.add(".Net Framework");
    child.add("PHP");
    childItem.add(child);

    /**
     * Add Data For Mobile
     */
    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Android");
    child.add("Window Mobile");
    child.add("iPHone");
    child.add("Blackberry");
    childItem.add(child);
    /**
     * Add Data For Manufacture
     */
    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("HTC");
    child.add("Apple");
    child.add("Samsung");
    child.add("Nokia");
    childItem.add(child);
    /**
     * Add Data For Extras
     */
    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Contact Us");
    child.add("About Us");
    child.add("Location");
    child.add("Root Cause");
    childItem.add(child);


}
```

Now i want do do an action by triggering an if statement when some of the children is selected:

```
if(childItem.getText(childPosition) == "Java"){

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);

    }
```

However it is not working. I wonder if there's a way to get text from lets say child.add("Java"); so that if statement work and triggers an action?

Comment: `"Java".equals(childItem.get(childPosition))`

Comment: Don't use `==` with strings, use `.equals`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
if("Java".equals(childItem.getText(childPosition)))
```

As `==` compares references while `equals()` compares values

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more info

Answer (score 2):

The string comparison `string1 == string2` will check the reference not the value of each object

You should use `string1.equals(string2)`, which would compare the values in each object.

In your case it is

```
if(childItem.getText(childPosition).equals("Java")){

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);

}
```

You can find some cool answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) post.

Hope it helped solve your problem.

Comment: it gives me error: "the method getText(int is undefined for the type ArrayList<Object>"